# Round corners is not working in all simulators except iPhone XS max and XR

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, rounded-corners

**i am using round corner for my collection view cells, this is working fine in iPhone XS Max and XR, but round corner is not showing in others. below is the code which i am using.**

---

```
 class ButtonCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var buttonImage: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var buttonTitle: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var cellBackGroundView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageWidthContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageHeightContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

        override func awakeFromNib() {
             super.awakeFromNib()
             self.applyShadow(shadowColor: UIColor.gray, shadowRadious: 4, shadowOpacity: 1)
           makeRoundedCorners()

        }

        func makeRoundedCorners() {
             cellBackGroundView.roundCorners(corners: .allCorners, radius: 15)
        }

        func setupImageSize(cellType : String){
            if cellType == "12" {
                imageWidthContraint.constant = 40
                imageHeightContraint.constant = 50
            }else if cellType == "13"{
                imageWidthContraint.constant = 62
                imageHeightContraint.constant = 34
            }
        }

    }
```

---

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.mask = mask
        mask.path = path.cgPath

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
extension UIView {

    func roundCorners(radius: CGFloat) {

        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I dont think you need f`unc roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat)`

Answer (score 0):

As far as trouble shooting I recommend the following steps.

in your simulator print out the `cornerRadius`, after assigning a value to it. In my case, I was assigning 0 to it unintentionally.

```
(lldb) po style.cornerRadius
6.0

(lldb) po layer.cornerRadius
0.0
```

The reason was that I had a computed value misspelled which was assigning the view's current corner radius.

```swift
    var sytle: Style {
        .init(cornerRadius: layer.cornerRadius, bgColor: backgroundColor)
    }
```